# MITM: sslstrip + mitmdump

Tags: man-in-the-middle, sslstrip

I'm doing some MITM injection with mitmdump (mitmproxy):

```
 mitmdump -s 'injection.py' -m transparent
```

it works perfectly (over HTTP) as intended.

Then I heard of SSLstrip :

```
sslstrip -l 8080
```

which works as intended as well.

But I don't understand how to do my "own injection" (injection.py) + SSLstrip.

Running mitmdump after SSLstrip or vice versa tells me that 8080 is already in use.

```
Error starting proxy server: OSError(98, 'Address already in use')
```

How to combine SSLstrip + mitmdump? How to run an external injection script (injection.py) + SSLstrip? Is there an other/better way?

Comment: You can replicate most of sslstrip's functionality using one of the example scripts included with mitmproxy: https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/examples/complex/sslstrip.py Your custom injection logic could be added to this file.

Comment: Hello, thank you for this answer! that will do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replicate SSLStrip's functionality using a Mitmproxy script. In the examples directory of the Mitmproxy source tree, see [sslstrip.py](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/examples/complex/sslstrip.py).

You can simply modify the request or response functions in this script to perform the custom injection that your own script does.